# error when using -fsanitize=undefined : runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I added -fsanitize=undefined to my unittests projects and now i get runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0x... for type 'vanguard::Server'.

I have this line in my code, and from what i read, this should be where the error is.

`m_facade(reinterpret_cast<vanguard::Server*>(std::integral_constant<uintptr_t, 0x87654321>::value)`

vanguard::Server requires 8 byte alignment. I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: `0x87654321` is not a multiple of 8.  What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: Take a look at that address `0x87654321` again... Does that look like it's "8 byte" aligned? Where did you even get that number from? Few pointers will ever be odd, unless they're pointing into the middle of a `char` string or similar.

Comment: It is company code, not sure where 0x87654321 comes from. But i tried changing it to  0x80000000 is a multiple of 8 and it still doesn't work, so that's not the problem. Edit: made comment more explicit

Comment: Are you sure address `0x80000000` points to an actual `vanguard::Server`?  In modern OS'es, address space is randomized and the addresses from one run can be completely different from another run.

Comment: Your company should be attempting to adhere to some secure coding practices. [This](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/MEM54-CPP.+Provide+placement+new+with+properly+aligned+pointers+to+sufficient+storage+capacity) page doesn't address the same issue, but the guidance on memory alignment still follows. There's a chance that [MEM-57](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/MEM57-CPP.+Avoid+using+default+operator+new+for+over-aligned+types) could apply as well.

Comment: This is legacy 32bit code? And how can one possibly use a constant in that context? I can't fathom how that would work; even if you knew that you had allocated a huge chunk of memory all to yourself you would still work from the offset of that allocation; you would not use a constant.

Comment: If the code you show passed any kind of test or review to enter production at your company, then someone (or several someones more likely) made some really bad judgement calls. That code is ***bad***, plain and simple, and shouldn't have been written in the first place. The only place where something like that would be remotely acceptable would be on some direct-to-hardware system, and even then the odd address is, well, *odd*.